# How to add comment inside complex excel formula

Tags: excel

Is it possible to add a comment within the cell of an excel formula?  I have an exceedingly long expression inside a cell that could better understood if I can comment within it.

Excel 2010 is my version.  Here is an example cell I'd like to notate:

```
=MID(
A4,
((FIND("n   ",A4,FIND(G4,A4))+75)+LEN(H4)+78),
(FIND("n   ",A4,(FIND("n   ",A4,FIND(G4,A4))+75))) - ((FIND("n   ",A4,FIND(G4,A4))+78))
)
```

Comment: You could add a comment to the cell, as in a bubble that appears when clicked on.  Or you could split your formula into multiple cells and explain with a title row what each do.  These can be outside the printable and normal view area.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think Scott's method is the cleaner usage; if your formula is already long/complex enough to need explaining, then having the comment 'outside of' the cell could help keep things cleaner. And splitting formulas into multiple cells is a good way to show step-by-step how you obtain your values, which is particularly important if someone is reviewing your methods.

Answer (score 32):

Like this:

```
=SUM(A1:A4)+N("This is a comment")
```

http://www.howtogeek.com/162231/add-comments-to-formulas-and-cells-in-excel-2013/

Comment: Very interesting usage - the N() function converts text to 0, so anything you write ends up being ignored by the formula. I generally prefer using the actual comment system, but there are times when that is not possible [comments may be used by your company for review notes only, etc.].

Comment: Yes it's OK as long as the formula gives a numeric result.

Comment: If you had something like =IFERROR(A1/A2,"")+N("comment") it would go wrong if A2=0 so I can't totally endorse it.

Answer (score 13):

For the problem Tom Sharpe mentions in the Answer by Ben Rhys-Lewis, there is a solution. Well, being Excel, probably five or six, but:

For text functions you wish to append a comment to, use something like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(IFERROR(A1/A2,""),T(N("comment")))
```

N() will return a "0" which T() will then make into an Excel blank. It acts like "" in a formula in that it adds nothing to or into a string though it will not be a null if you paste values with it... an Excel "blank" is born.

Note that it works with the math if the division does not result in an error because while Excel makes text out fo the result, in the cell, it uses it as a number for math done on that cell's text-number result (for instance, a text "3.5" will still add to a numerical 9.5 in another cell tha that adds 6 to the "3.5" in the cell).

Also, to make the comments stand out, you can break the piece of your formula with Alt-Enter right before and right after that piece and its comment. Not like real commenting, but standing out more than some horrid muddle that it just increased stands out, enough worth doing and you can almost always add spaces before the comment as well:

```
=function stuff function stuff
CONCATENATE(IFERROR(A1/A2,""),    T(N("comment")))
and a bit more function stuff and more and more and so on...
```

Comment: Or, if you don't want the word **CONCATENATE** and an extra set of parentheses uglifying your formula, you could use this: `=IFERROR(A1/A2,"") & T(N("comment"))`, which is essentially equivalent but looks cleaner. Another advantage (a marginal one, since this is very unlikely to ever be an issue), is that **CONCATENATE** has a 255 character length limit and **&** doesn't.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the LET function like this:

```
=LET(
comment, "my comment",
SUM(P4:P10))
```

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. It doesn't translate to Google Sheets or Libre Office, but for pure Excel it's spot on.

Answer (score 9):

The N() comment function **does not have to be the last portion** of the function.  So this is a workable solution:

=+C6+N("description of C6 variable")  +C7+N("C7 info")  +C8+N("C8 info")

While not required, for improved readability I use params to indicate the comment refers to several elements. For this example the first comment just refers to "q13" cell while the next two comments refer to the calculation between the "(...)"

=+AA435 * q13+N(bonus multiplier) +(c435*$d$4/a435)+N("profit scaled by area") +(p24*$q$5 + w12*3)+N("blah...")

I always prefer to break up long complex formulas into a single simple consolidation formula that adds together hidden columns of intermediate formulas.

Answer (score 8):

The [LET function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) that was [released in 2020](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/let-names-in-formulas-generally-available/ba-p/1878903) (available to Microsoft 365 subscribers) makes it possible to rewrite complex formulas in a more readable way by using variables. As Jim Pearson points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67002574/14148248), you can also include comments as variables that are not used in the formula.

Here is one of many ways you could rewrite your formula with variable names that help understand the different parts of the formula:

```
=LET(\0, "Extract characters from text based on the contents of the other columns.",
     text, A4,
     find_string_G, FIND(G4, text),
     find_string_n, FIND("n   ", text, find_string_G),
     start_num, (find_string_n+75) + LEN(H4) + 78,
     num_chars, FIND("n   ", text, (find_string_n+75)) - (find_string_n+78),
MID(text, start_num, num_chars)
)
```