# Excel formula - can I add (multiple) comments into the formula itself?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Inside a complex Excel2010 formula, is there a way to embed a comment "within a section of the complex formula", so that certain sections (for example, IF-THEN statements) can be commented; allowing on-the-fly analysis of the formula?

I've read this post ([How to add comment inside complex excel formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203307/how-to-add-comment-inside-complex-excel-formula)) which covers the basic function of adding comment text to the overall cell with "+N()", but I'm looking for a way to have multiple comments within the formula - similar to REM statements in a DOS batch file, or single-quote comments in VBA code.

Example - my formula (in a basic form):

```
=IF($C69="","cust is blank", 
IF($AL69<>"#",
    IF(MONTH($AL69)=$I$5,
        "CM","err"),
    IFERROR(IF(MONTH($AI69+INDEX('Check Grades'!$A$108:$D$112,MATCH($C69,'Check Grades'!$A$108:$A$112,0),4))=$I$5,
    "NM (late)",
    "NM (DGI)"
    ),
    "no DGI"
    )
  )
)
```

I'd like to input comments for each IF section, if at all possible:

```
=IF($C69="","cust is blank",  *If C69 is blank, then customer not listed*
IF($AL69<>"#",            *If AL69 is NOT blank, then check for a valid month*
    IF(MONTH($AL69)=$I$5,
        "CM","err"),
    IFERROR(IF(MONTH($AI69+INDEX('Check Grades'!$A$108:$D$112,MATCH($C69,'Check Grades'!$A$108:$A$112,0),4))=$I$5,
    "NM (late)",
    "NM (DGI)"            *If AI69 plus a lookup value = I5, 'late' else 'on-time'*
    ),
    "other"
    )
  )
)
```

...etcetera...

It looks like the +N() function works simply 'after' a formula. Yes, I can (& for the time being, will) split each section into different cells, but in the end, I'll need to combine them. During development of the complex formula, the comments can help me debug, and when all is done, I can paste them all into an external comment; but still, if this multi-comment-in-a-cell is possible, would like to use...

Comment: I know this is not the solution that you are looking for, but have a look at FormulaDesk which is free: https://www.formuladesk.com/
It can break down complex formulas without having to use multiple cells, making it easier to understand and edit them.

Comment: Can you describe a little more what your general goal is? A user who is using those formulas, I would assume understand it... It's an interesting question but there may be alternatives to what you want than putting comments *inside* a formula, which I personally haven't ever come across before.

Comment: @BruceWayne - I've worked with VBA comments, and in this case, needed to create a formula instead of a macro.
I now have to put in some formulas to create a 'corrected' data column for a pivot table to use, instead of a macro to create that new column.
I won't be around in future, so I want to comment the code, "ideally" within it, so that any future adjustments, can have the comments adjusted as they work through it.
I can make comments separately, but bottom line, I wasn't sure if this was at all possible; if so, I have a variety of formulas I'd love to add comments to.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense.  I hope you are able to find an answer, as it's an interesting question.  My only thought would be to have some "master spreadsheet" with the formulas, and then comments next to it. Then, store that on a drive accessible to anyone who may need it, so they can go there to check it out.  ...again, it's not an answer that puts the comments *in* the formulas, but it's an alternative.

Comment: FWIW, I usually add a tab at the end named "About" or "Details" that documents the formulas and other design aspects that seem to need commentary.

Comment: The ideal formula/subrutine/method explains itself. Can you maybe use named references instead of A1 notation? Maybe use tables with well defined names? Maybe add conditional formatting and a legend? Maybe add classic comments to input cells and values? Give a tour of the spreadsheet to the next guy. :-)

Comment: Maybe cut out the middle man, ex. cust is blank = customer not listed?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend spliting the complex formula into multiple parts/cells.

But if that is not an option, you **can** use the N() function in multiple locations, where the returned "0" value will not make a calculation/logical error.
I admit, I didn't study your formula to understand, if this is the case. I leave that privilege to you.

Here is an example of multiple N() functions not messing things up.

`=N("Let me tell you a story,")+(SUM($B$2:$B$3)+N(" about a handful of comments,"))/COUNT($C$2:$C$5)+N(" that went to SO.")`

The result is correct = 0+(20+0)/4 + 0 = 5.

[image]