# Adding a comment as a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, comments

How to automate a comment on an Excel Sheet? Is there a formula to create a comment like `"= Comment("etc")"` or else?

For example, In a column with a short introduction about every row, I figured a comment would be better than a long text in every cell.

Other alternatives are welcomed as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add comment inside complex excel formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203307/how-to-add-comment-inside-complex-excel-formula)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns this N function is a comment for a formula, it's not an excel comment.

Comment: What do you meamn exactly by "how to automate a comment?" do you need the comment text to be auto-generated?

Comment: A formula won't be able to create a comment in a cell.  You could possible use a worksheet event to insert and update the comment if using VBA is ok.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Would either **Shring to fit** or **wrapping text** work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple answer using VBA would be to create a VBA function like this:

```
Option Explicit

Function InsertComment(Stringincell As String, StrinComment As String)
   Application.Caller.ClearComments
   Application.Caller.AddComment StrinComment
   InsertComment = Stringincell
End Function
```

Now you use your regular excel and enter the function/formula in a cell to get your text as a comment:

```
=Comment("String to see in the cell","String you want to see in the comment")
```

Comment: I didn't think that would work as it's changing something other than the value.  One change I'd make is to change `Selection` to `Application.Caller`.   `Selection` could add a comment to the wrong cell - `=InsertComment("ABC",J7)` updating J7 will add the comment to J7.  `Application.Caller` will refer to the cell containing the formula.

Comment: Definitely a good comment, also if you want to pull the formula!

Comment: Thank you for that, you've solved my problem. I literally stopped checking this thread because all I got is comments that were not even related to what i asked, a suggestion to a question that isn't even similar to mine, other comments that are meant to be annoying and a down vote, yet they couldn't do it themselves. Literally makes a person stop carrying... But it was worth it for now i have your answer, so thanks.

Comment: I m glad I could help. I guess the downvote was because the question doesn t fit the style of Stackoverflow that much. Maybe the question should have been more on Superuser. I have proposed an Edit to make it a better upvotable question :)

Answer (score 1):

To add the contents of every cell to a comment tied to that cell, you can use the `AddComment` method in VBA:

```
Sub comment()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Worksheets(1)
Set rng = ws.UsedRange

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        c.AddComment.Text c.Formula
    Next c


End Sub
```

This will also show non-formula cell contents. If you want to determine whether this is an actual formula, you can use an `if` statement with `application.WorksheetFunction.IsFormula(range(c.address))` to get a boolean value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `IsFormula` was introduced in Excel 2013 I think. As it's VBA `c.HasFormula` will return the same in all versions (maybe not earlier than 2003).